# In C++, can you define a variable in terms of other variables that have already been defined?

Tags: c++, variables

For example, can I define a variable "z" in terms of variables I already defined called "x" and "y" (yes I know these are horrible naming conventions but it's an example). Like this:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = x * y;
```

Can you do something like that and just go on with your program or will you get error messages?

Comment: You can try it out yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in *lambdas*:

```cpp
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
auto z = [&x, &y](){ return x * y; };
```

This code does exactly what you are requesting: calling the `z()` function would always give you the result that is the multiplication of the `x` and `y` variables:

```cpp
int v = z();
assert(v == x * y);
```

Even if `x` or `y` change you would always get their multiplication:

```cpp
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
auto z = [&x, &y](){ return x * y; };
assert(z() == 0);
x = 1;
y = 2;
assert(z() == 2);
```

Comment: This is possibly a good point. Many beginners think that writing `int z = x * y;` acts like a spreadsheet, so `z` will always have the value given by multiplying the **current** values of `x` and `y`. This code will do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker at least I cannot believe that the author asks for an advice how to assign `z = x * y`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dmitry! I am a beginner, obviously. In response to Pete Becker's comment, is he saying that if I have code "int z = x * y;" that it will not automatically update the value of z based on how x and y change?

Comment: @RahizKhan yes, that is what he is saying. The initialization/assignment `int z = x * y` is a one-off event, and is never reevaluated. Lambdas is the opposite: is reevaluated every time you call it. I recommend you to update your question because the majority did not understand your intentions. Please clearly indicate if you need a one-off event or the "a la spreadsheat" behavior.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov thank you for your response. it is very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

> can I define a variable "z" in terms of variables I already defined called "x" and "y"

```
int z = x * y;
```

Totally possible to define `z` that way. Most if not all languages should allow that basic definition. Except, perhaps you have to be careful with overflow issue. If later in your program you may assign `x` and `y` to very large value, then `z` could overflow. It may be better to do:

```
long long z = x * y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Also,

```
int x = 1, y = x;
int z=x*y;
```

`y = x;`  is possible.